# How to override JUnit Test Suite default output

Tags: java, testing, junit, annotations, test-suite

I am running Junit Test Runner as TestRunner.run(suite) within a java main method and running that locally which succesfully runs . What I am stuck is that every test suite i run from the comamnd line produces a

OK (1 test) ...
OK (2 test) ...

I dont want this behavior . Is there is some way i can get rid of this ? I have searched a lot and no one seems to be tackling this .

The Method Rule and Class rule annotations seem to be handling things at a suite level (interceptors) but i am not able to override the suite output that junit provides

Any pointers on this is much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `TestRunner` class has a `setPrinter(ResultPrinter)` method on it that allows you to override what happens to the output.  You can also pass one into the constructor.  By default the printer is:

```
new ResultPrinter(System.out);
```

If you, for example subclass the `ResultPrinter` you could turn off the successful output.  Something like this should work:

```
public class MyResultPrinter extends ResultPrinter {
    public MyResultPrinter(PrintStream writer) {
        super(writer);
    }
        @Override
    protected void printFooter(TestResult result) {
        if (result.wasSuccessful()) {
            // just drop the OK messages
        } else {
            // but print the failures
            super.printFooter(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you'd use it like:

```
new TestRunner(new MyResultPrinter(System.out)).run(suite);
```